# Android Webview to open session related page

Tags: android, wordpress, webview

i want to open a wordpress page in android webview

URL of the page is:
"http://www.mydomain.com/dashboard"

dashboard page comes after login is done by user and a wordpress session is maintained.

now my question to you is can i send login parameters or something else to maintain wordpress session to open dashboard page directly in android?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved this issue myself,

Steps:

1) Created a php file on server that i used in android webview
2) in that php file i used wordpress function of auto login to create wordpress session as wp session are different then others.
3) after auto logging in i redirected user to dashboard board page

pretty simple hmm?